# Identity or Non Identity Matrix

Tags: python

So basically i want to write a program to display a matrix using lists and to print out whether the matrix is an identity matrix or not.

```
R = int(input('Enter no. of rows:'))
C = int(input('Enter no of columns:'))
print('Enter row wise entries:')
Mat = []
for i in range(R):
    a = []
    for j in range(C):
        a.append(int(input()))
    Mat.append(a)
for i in range(R):
    for j in range(C):
        print(Mat[i][j], end=' ')
    print()
for i in range(R):
    for j in range(C):
        if i != j and Mat[i][j] != 0 or i == j and Mat[i][j] == 1:
            break      
print('Identity Matrix')
```

I am able to print out the matrix but not able to properly check if its an identity one or not. Please check my code and tell me whats wrong.

Comment: You can check with `np.eye` or `np.identity` rather than doing a loop.

Comment: @Austin he doesnt use numpy

Comment: `if (i != j and Mat[i][j] != 0) or (i == j and Mat[i][j] != 1):` also check `if C == R`

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems really close to me!

The only things I would change are:

- checking if the number of columns == number of rows
- in the second part of the if statement to check each element you check if i==j and Mat[i][j] == 1, but the correct check for a matrix not being identity should be Mat[i][j] != 1
- Add a flag to keep track of whether the matrix was identity or not in the checks you made

```
R = int(input('Enter no. of rows:'))
C = int(input('Enter no of columns:'))
print('Enter row wise entries:')
Mat = []
for i in range(R):
    a = []
    for j in range(C):
        a.append(int(input()))
    Mat.append(a)
for i in range(R):
    for j in range(C):
        print(Mat[i][j], end=' ')
    print()
isIdentity = True
if C == R: # change 1
    for i in range(R):
        for j in range(C):
            if (i != j and Mat[i][j] != 0) or (i == j and Mat[i][j] != 1): # change 2
                isIdentity = False # change 3
                break
else:
    isIdentity = False
if isIdentity:   
    print('Identity Matrix')
else:
    print('Not Identity Matrix')
```